# How to handle png from rest api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, http, wcf

Right now, I'm creating a **WCF** service that sends a location to the Bing Map API and returns a PNG image to the service client. Currently, I copied a working api example from their documentation webpage, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how I can pass it on.

From other stackoverflow questions, I started by converting the response, and I got it into `Base64`. But it triggered and received an error, that says input is not in `Base64` form.

[A screenshot of what input looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg90M.png)

```
public string getResponse()
{
    string key = [My Api Key];

    Uri geocodeRequest = new Uri(string.Format("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q={0}&key={1}", query, key));
    Uri imageryRequest = new Uri(string.Format("https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/Redmond Washington?ms=500,270&zl=12&&c=en-US&he=1&key={0}", key));

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imageryRequest);
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    //Handling the response in PNG
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

    string input = reader.ReadToEnd();

    byte[] data = convert.FromBase64String(input);
    return data;


}
```

Comment: The image you attached looks like the header of a PNG file when opened in a text editor. Try reading is a ByteArray instead and saving that to a file.

Answer (score 0):

It already is a PNG image as `byte[]`. Also, keep in mind that the image returned is not guaranteed to be `PNG`, `JPEG`, or `GIF`. It returns what it feels is the most appropriate image type unless [a specific type is requested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_3).

ex. `fmt=jpeg`

[image: Map image]

You just need to do something with it. In my example, I saved it to a file. You probably just need to return the `byte[]`.

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
public static async void GetResponse()
{
    string key = Properties.Settings.Default.Key;

    Uri imgUri = new Uri($"https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/Redmond Washington?ms=500,270&zl=12&&c=en-US&he=1&fmt=png&key={key}");

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(imgUri);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    byte[] responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

    File.WriteAllBytes("test.png", responseData);
}
```